# Postgres not recognizing created users

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-10

I've just installed a PostgreSQL 10 on Ubuntu 18.04. I have `postres` default user setup with a password.

I created some users and databases but I'm getting this error. How do I get passed this?

```
:~$ sudo -i -u myUser01
sudo: unknown user: myUser01
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I verified they exist:

```
                                      List of roles
    Role name    |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 myUser01        | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 myUser02        | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 postgres        | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}



                                 List of databases
      Name       |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges   
-----------------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 myUser01        | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 myUser02        | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 postgres        | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 template0       | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                 |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1       | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                 |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

Here's my etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf. Notice I have DB admin set to `md5` instead of `peer` in case this matters.

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: It looks like you're confusing database users with operating system users. Use `psql` or something similar to connect to the database with those database users.

Comment: What are the series of commands for that?

Comment: In other words, after  sudo -i -u postgres,how do I connect with the db users?

Comment: The command `psql` is probably enough, or `psql -U myUser01` to connect with your user.

Comment: How do you want to connect?  Did you assign passwords to the new users?  Is that how you want to connect?  If so, you need to change "peer" to "md5" for everyone, not just for postgres.

Comment: I realized what I was doing wrong. I made a user that matches up with my linux user.